# Convert 120v to 240v and run inverter/charger?

Tags: electrical, 240v, transformer, adapter

Currently I have a generator that outputs 240v/30A via a L14-30R generator transfer cable.  I hook this to my inverter/charger to charge the batteries in my off-grid cabin.  The Inverter/Charger requires 240V in to operate.  Works well, and I'm happy with it.

The problem is that I live by the phrase "Two is one, one is none."

I do have a smaller generator on-site, but it only outputs @ 120v.  I'm wondering if I can convert voltage to work as a backup for the primary gen?

Could I use a step-up transformer to convert the smaller generator's 120v to 240v, then an adapter to change the plug format to the L14-30R on the generator transfer cable?

Comment: did you look at the size of the transformer you will need ?

Comment: A generator that only has 120 will probably be too small, not enough power to run the big charger.  Will probably be better to get a smaller charger or sell that generator and get a bigger one.

Comment: Amazon sells one, it notably doesn't have UL markings on it.

Comment: You are also obliged to live in the phrase "don't put 10 pounds in a 5 pound bag". Please post the nameplate data off the battery charger and generator. Don't you want a second battery charger given your credo?